# Explode and str_replace

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
while (strpos($r, "[url]") !== FALSE){
    $link = explode("[url]", $r);
    $final_link = explode("[/url]", $link[0]);

    $thelink = $final_link[0];
}
$r = str_replace("[url]","[url=$thelink]",$r);
```

If `$r = [url]www.google.com[/url]`, I need to turn this into `[url=www.google.com]www.google.com[/url]`

This code doesn't seem to be doing it. Have I missed something?
Give me a 500 error!

Thanks

Comment: A string arrives such as the $r = I posted in the question. I need to turn that into what I wrote. The code is attempting to break it down and build it up in the alternate format.

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, when you explode you are effectively stripping out the [url] so there is nothing to be replaced.  Have you printed out $thelink to see what it looks like?

Comment: You probably want to move the last line to inside the while, otherwise it is an infinite loop as $r is never modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('~\[url\](.*?)\[/url\]~', '[url=$1]$1[/url]', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$r = '[url]www.google.com[/url]';
if (strpos($r, "[url]") !== FALSE){
    $link = explode("[url]", $r);
    $final_link = explode("[/url]", $link[1]);

    $thelink = $final_link[0];
    $r = str_replace("[url]","[url=$thelink]",$r);
}

var_dump($r);
```

Changes are: changed the `while` to an `if` as there doesn't seem to be a reason for it being a `while`. Also changed `$link[0]` to `$link[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't directly answer your (not very good!) question I would recommend using a regular expression instead:

```
$outputText = preg_replace('/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/i', '[url=$1]$1[/url]', $inputText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = preg_replace('#\[url\](.*?)\[/url\]#', '[url=$1]$1[/url]', $r);
```

Try that regular expression instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = "[url]www.google.com[/url]";
$sub="=".substr($r,5,-6);
echo $url=substr_replace($r,$sub,4,0);
```